# How to fix overlapping content in ion-slide

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ion-slide to display some list of lessons on **ionic 3**.
However, some contents are overlapping. How can I fixed this so the contents can be contained possibly via scroll. See image.
[image]

Comment: I do not see any overlap. We need you help to understand the problem. First, clarify where is the overlapping. Second, shows the relevant code.

Comment: height: fit-content; in the scss file fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is with the skip button "pushing" down your content, I would suggest moving your "skip" button into the header. This is also in line with how UX should work (leveraging top panel for actions like skip)

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Lesson 1
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons>
      <button ion-button (click)="startApp()">SKIP</button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

But in general I would suggest you to see how Ionic recommends to do this type of UX components.

For that create a new project using: **ionic start MyApp super**

this will load in built template of an app that has walkthrough component you need (it will be called "tutorial" in pages folder of this project)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sergey, but I was able to fix it by modifying my scss file. thus: height: fit-content;